# How to find value that contains all values from another table?

Tags: mysql, relational-division

If I had these tables

```
+--------+-----+ 
|   ID   | oid | 
+--------+-----+ 
| 0      |  1  | 
| 2      |  1  | 
| 0      |  2  | 
+--------+-----+ 
+--------+ 
|   num  |
+--------+ 
| 1      | 
| 2      | 
+--------+
```

I would get ID 0 back because it has both num 1 and 2.

How would I go about getting that?

Comment: I voted to close this as a duplicate of another question. The other question was asked about Microsoft SQL Server, but this problem — relational division — and its solution is independent of the brand of SQL.

Comment: @BillKarwin I don't think any of the answers will solve delishas's problem, I will vote to reopen

Comment: Re the BCNF question you just deleted: Presuming that your FD set is a cover, none of the FDs determine B or D so those must be in any CK. BDA & BDE are CKs but so is BDC & there are no more. Even if we ignored whether your CK set & decomposition are correct & just considered the 1st question sentence "Is R2 in BCNF?", if you don't know how to answer that then you need to try to answer it & ask a question about following & being stuck or finished in applying quoted/referenced (authoritative) definition(s) and/or algorithm(s).